Multiple Select will create empty json if nothing is selected
i have a problem, regarding a multiple select.
I have a Multiple Select like bleow.
echo '<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 10px">
    <select  class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="status[]" multiple size="5"  style="width: 140px">
            <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
            <option value="ONHOLD">On Hold</option>
            <option value="ONGOING">Ongoing</option>
            <option value="CHANCELED">Chanceled</option>
            <option value="CLOSED">Closed</option>
    </select>
    </td>';

To plot a Canvasjs with the Filter of the Multiple Selection i'm getting the array via json_encode into an Variable:
var status = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['status']); ?>;

Then i handed it over to the graph, to use it as Filter
$.getJSON("fertigung/graph/mes/autocomplete/getdata_downcases_daily.php?type=json", {status: status}, function(data) {
        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            dataPoints1.push({ x: data[i].x, y: data[i].y }); 
        }
        chart1.render();
    });

Everything is working as long as something is selected and the status [] array is not empty.
Now here is the problem, if nothing is selected the array is not there or empty.
How can i set the array to an Value of '%' before using json_encode.
I tried to fill the Array with a Value if nothing is selected, but was not succesful so far.

Are you asking how to insert an element into the empty array, that contains the text %? if(!count($_REQUEST['status'])) { $_REQUEST['status'] = ['%']; } ...?

fyi: CHANCELED is a misspelling, that should be CANCELLED most likely?. Would a hidden input before the select not work for you?

I added a hidden Input type before, now the array is always % and couldn' be changed by the multiple select anymore.
`echo '';
echo '
      <select name="status[]" multiple size="5" style="width: 140px">
  <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
  <option value="ONHOLD">On Hold</option>
  <option value="ONGOING">Ongoing</option>
  <option value="CHANCELED">Chanceled</option>
  <option value="CLOSED">Closed</option>...`


Provide a default value in PHP when nothing is sent.
var status = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['status'] ?? ['%']); ?>;

